# My Launchpad doesn't create a db file and keeps resetting its layout

Tags: macos, high-sierra, launchpad

Whenever I move around icons in Launchpad, then log out and back in, the layout resets to factory defaults. And for some reason, Launchpad doesn't create it's db file. Why?